# A sort of extension of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: determinant, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, positive-semidefinite

Let $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, $i = 1,\dotsb,n$ be real numbers. Denote $S_{pq}:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{p}b_{i}^{q}$.

I want to show that,
$$ (S_{20}S_{02} - S_{11}^2)S_{00} - (S_{10}S_{02} - S_{01}S_{11})S_{10} + (S_{10}S_{11} - S_{01}S_{20})S_{01} \geq 0,$$
and find the condition on $a$ and $b$ for this inequality to become an equality.

I thought about it in several ways, and one of them is that the left-hand side(LHS) of the inequality is the determinant of the matrix defined below:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
S_{00} & S_{10} & S_{01} \\
S_{10} & S_{20} & S_{11} \\
S_{01} & S_{11} & S_{02} 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Also, I have a mere feeling that it is somewhat connected to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. A high-dimensional version of it, maybe?

In addition, I found out that if $n=2$, then (LHS) is always 0. This made me think of typical version of Cauchy-Schwarz, where
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i})^{2} \geq 0 $$
Here, if $n=1$ then it becomes an equality.

This is one of the reasons that I think the inequality is somewhat related to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Actually I managed to prove it in a geometric way (not perfectly sure though), but I want a proof in more simple and of an algebraic way. Thanks in advance for any help or hint.

Edit: I'm wondering now if I can show that the matrix is nonnegative definite.

Comment: @AnneBauval The proof in a geometric way is about the inequality itself but is somewhat hard to write down...
Sorry about the wrong expression of (expected) equivalence condition. Please forget it.
Actually I'm wondering now if I can show that the matrix is nonnegative definite.

Comment: @AnneBauval The condition of a and b when the inequality becomes an equality.

Comment: Thank you. I edited your post to insert your words.. I also added the tag "positive-semi-definite". This is certainly what you meant instead of "nonnegative definite".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
S_{00} & S_{10} & S_{01} \\
S_{10} & S_{20} & S_{11} \\
S_{01} & S_{11} & S_{02} 
\end{pmatrix} = A^T A
$$
where $A$ is the $n \times 3$ matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & a_1 & b_1 \\
1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & a_n & b_n  
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$

It follows that
$$
 x^T S x = \Vert A x \Vert^2 \ge 0
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R^3$, i.e. $S$ is positive semidefinite. It follows that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ of $S$ are (real and) nonnegative and $\det(S) = \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3 \ge 0$.

- If the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent then $Sx = A^TAx = 0$ for some nonzero vector $x$, so that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $S$ and $\det(S) = 0$. This is always the case if $n \le 2$.
- If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent then $x^T S x > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $x$, so that $S$ is positive definite and $\det(S) > 0$.